# Adding a prefix N for a parameter in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, unicode-string

How can I add a prefix N for a parameter in stored procedure?

For example: in an insert/update/select statement we can do it like

```
insert into table xxx values (N'value')

Alter table set value = N'value1'

etc..
```

I want to add prefix to resolve the inverted question mark(¿) issue in the Oracle table column of type `nvarchar2` for some characters like - (hyphen), TM (trade mark symbol) etc..

Comment: Did you figure out a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're saying, you would just concatenate the string onto the value:

```
insert into table xxx values ('N'||value_1, value_2, value_3);
```

If your prefix isn't a fixed string, you could use a parameter:

```
prefix_1 := 'N';
insert into table xxx values (prefix_1||value_1, value_2, value_3);
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is confusing, I'm looking something like this N'value1'' like this, value1 is the parameter for stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, we can declare a local variable inside procedure to achieve it.
Not sure about how and if possible to include it in the IN parameter.

```
CREATE TABLE so_nvarchar_test (col1 NVARCHAR2(100)) ;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE validate_nvarchar2(p_parameter NVARCHAR2)
IS
   validated_param NVARCHAR2(100) := N''||p_parameter||'';
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO so_nvarchar_test(col1) VALUES (validated_param);
END;
/

DECLARE
   p_parameter NVARCHAR2(100) := 'Länsförsäkringar?';
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO so_nvarchar_test(col1) VALUES (p_parameter);
END;
/
```